# TXT to SQL that automatically removes that line of txt once complete

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin that exports form entries to a txt file. So I need to write a php script to add them to a sql database as I want the submissions added to a database on a different domain (otherwise I’d just get the plugin to do it for me). I’m fine about how I get it to connect to the database, it’s just how I code it to interpret the data as the column names are always next to the field as shown.

{"Entry_ID":"235","Name":"matt","Email":"matt@gmail.com","Date":"03/10/2017"}{"Entry_ID":"236","Name":"matt","Email":"matt@btinternet.com","Date":"10/10/2017"}

Is there a way to get it to ignore the column name and only interpret the data within the “” after the : ?

Once these have been added to the sql database I would then need to get the lines removed from the txt

So far I have this but it isn't working...

```
$file= fopen('http://mpcreations.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/red-seal-resources/test.txt', 'r');
while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $object = json_encode($data[0]);

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "INSERT INTO 'wp_forms' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';


if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $query)) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: The data looks like JSON. If you run `foreach(json_decode(trim(explode("\n",file_get_contents(filename.txt))), true) as $row) var_dump($row);`, you should see a bunch of arrays ready to be inserted into the db. If it doesn't work you'd need to split the commands up and check where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Each line in the txt file has JSON data? Process the txt file, parse the data and INSERT it into the database table.

```
$file= fopen('file.txt', 'r');
while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $object = json_encode($data[0]);

    // Prepare INSERT query here...
}
```